# Problema con la lectura de un texto y su validación

Tags: python, bucles

miren, estoy intentando hacer un codigo que tiene un input, al momento de poner el input el codigo lee lo puesto y tiene que encontrar si tiene una "a" o una "A" en el texto, si es asi da una respuesta y sino da otra.
El problema es que da igual si tiene la letra A o no solo se activa el print del if y no el del else

```
print("introduzca su texto")

valido=False


Texto=Input()


for i in range(len(Texto)):

   if Texto=="a" or "A":
      valido=True

if valido:
   print("Es valido")

else:
  print("No es valido")
```

En el input da igual si pongo A, Hola, B, a, o lo que sea que siempre sale "Es Valido", la unica ocasión en la que no salió valido es cuando le di al enter con el texto en blanco, es decir sin escribir nada.
Lo mejor es que tengo un codigo exactamente igual que solo cambia el texto y el "a" or "A": por un "@":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La línea

```
if Texto=="a" or "A":
```

contiene dos errores: el primero es que comparas **todo** el ingreso contra una letra, cuando deberías estar comparando solo una letra.

El segundo es el `or "A"`. Tu intención es preguntar si `Texto` es igual a la "a" minúscula o a la "A" mayúscula.

Python no lo interpreta así. Lo que viene después del `or` es una *expresión lógica*, que es evaluada para determinar su valor de verdad. La expresión en este caso es una simple constante "A", que es `True` por definición.

Por lo tanto, lo que Python ve es

```
if Texto=="a" or True:
```

lo que siempre ocurre.

La forma correcta es

```
if letra == "a" or letra == "A":
```

o alternativamente

```
if letra in "aA":
```

Otros puntos:

- Puedes combinar el `print` con el `input`.
- La forma de recorrer las letras de un texto es con un `for letra in texto`.
- Usa nombres en minúsculas para las variables, en mayúsculas para las clases.
- Una vez que encuentras la letra, usa `break` para no seguir buscando en el resto.

**Solución**

```
valido=False
texto=input("introduzca su texto")

for letra in texto:
    if letra =="a" or letra == "A":
        valido = True
        break

if valido:
    print("Es valido")
else:
    print("No es valido")
```

**Edición**

El código puede ser aún más compacto:

```
valido=False
texto=input("introduzca su texto")

if "a" in texto or "A" in texto:
    print("Es valido")
else:
    print("No es valido")
```

En lugar de recorrer el texto y preguntar letra por letra, simplemente preguntas si "a/A" está dentro del texto ingresado.